# tomee webservice doesn't deploy - asm error - Unable to create annotation scanner for web module simple-webservice: 43626

Tags: java, web-services, tomee-7

I am trying to deploy basic webservice template to tomee, I have tried windows 7 64 bit and windows 8 64 bit with java versions 1.8.0_25(64bit), 1.8.0_91(64bit) (this java version used to build code and run tomee). The webservice is basic example taken from internet - suorce code is below and well as the stack trace. Tomee 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 strait downloaded from internet with no code changes or jar changes. What could possibly cause this issue - do I need to replace default tomee jar(s) ?

code:

```
package org.superbiz.calculator.ws;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Stateless
@WebService ( portName = "CalculatorPort" , 
              serviceName = "CalculatorService" , 
              targetNamespace = "http://superbiz.org/wsdl" , 
              endpointInterface = "org.superbiz.calculator.ws.CalculatorWs" )
public class Calculator implements CalculatorWs
{
    public int sum( int add1 , int add2 )
    {
        return add1 + add2;
    }

    public int multiply( int mul1 , int mul2 )
    {
        return mul1 * mul2;
    }

    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
/* ################################## */
package org.superbiz.calculator.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService ( targetNamespace = "http://superbiz.org/wsdl" )
public interface CalculatorWs
{
    public int sum( int add1 , int add2 );

    public int multiply( int mul1 , int mul2 );

    public String hello();
}
```

stack trace:

```
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /host-manager
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\host-manager
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\host-manager" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\host-manager
INFO - using context file C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\host-manager\META-INF\context.xml
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\host-manager)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TL
Ds were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\host-manager has finished in 391 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager
INFO - using context file C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TL
Ds were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\manager has finished in 69 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\ROOT
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\ROOT
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\ROOT" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\ROOT
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\ROOT)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TL
Ds were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 60 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\simple-webservice
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /simple-webservice
SEVERE - ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/simple-webservice]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module simple-webse
rvice: 43626
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2256)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1151)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1112)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5093)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module simple-webservice: 43626
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:883)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:231)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2254)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 43626
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1170)
        at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:147)
        at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:160)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:875)
        ... 18 more
SEVERE - Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\simple-webservice
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].Stan
dardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/simple-webservice]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plus-7.0.0\webapps\simple-webservice has finished in 61 ms
INFO - Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
INFO - Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
INFO - Server startup in 621 ms
```

Comment: tried with jdk7 (build and running tomee) and get same error

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the class files might be corrupt and attempt to load it throwing this error, however the libraries do not help at all since they don't log what class its trying to load and finding same source code tomee is using (so I can add logging) is difficult since source code in maven and online seems to have different package names they the actual build binaries (strange). The only solution seems to be trial and error by removing a few (or one class at a time)